Relative path in Spyder not working even though set to current working directory and I can see in the file explorer the file is there
I have the following (simplified) code:
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
import os

os.chdir(directory where .py file is)

            #location for attachment,
            attach_HS= str("/Returns/"+df['NAME'][ind]+"/HS_"+df['NAME'][ind]+"_2023_24.xlsx") 
          
            # Open up an outlook email
            outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
            new_mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

            # Label the subject
            frs = str(df['NAME'][ind])
            subject = str(...)
            new_mail.Subject = subject

            # Add the to and cc list
            new_mail.SendUsingAccount = "x@x.uk"
            new_mail.To = str(df['MAIN_ CONTACT'][ind])
            new_mail.CC = "x@x.uk"

            #add the body of the message
            message_body = "Hi "+df['NAME'][ind]
            # Attach the file
            attachment1 = attach_HS

            # The file needs to be a string not a path object
            new_mail.Attachments.Add(Source=str(attachment1))

            # Display the email
            new_mail.Display(True)

I keep getting the error:
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Path does not exist. Verify the path is correct.', None, 0, -2147024893), None)

The current working directory is set in Spyder and then set again with os at the top of the script. I can see on the file explorer on the right hand side that the Returns folder exists and has the relevant folder inside it as well as the correct file, so why do I keep getting the same error? I've also tried setting the path with \ rather than / in case that was the issue. if I print attachment1 after it bugs out I get (with the correct name, redacted below):
'\\Returns\\df['NAME'][ind]\\LE_df['NAME'][ind]_2023_24.xlsx'

Thanks in advance for any help,
I couldn't find this specific problem, only issues when setting the current working directory.

If path starts with \ is not a relative path.

@GiacomoCatenazzi is correct but it looks like their comment didn't format correctly. If the path starts with a slash or backslash it is an absolute path, not a relative one.

Also I might try converting your relative path into the proper absolute path, e.g. with os.path.abspath

there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

why the indentation ?  syntax looks incorrect.

If you want relative paths, just do not start path with (back-)slash. I usually prefer to transform to absolute paths because I use it in error messages, and so I notice earlier if I run a script with wrong path.

Thanks @GiacomoCatenazzi and nekomatic , a mix of both your replies helped me fix it!

Thanks GiacomoCatenazzi and @nekomatic , a mix of both your replies helped me fix it!
